# cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: Cannot locate node of type [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]

Tags: ros, navigation, slam-gmapping, errors

`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: Cannot locate node of type [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]. Make sure file exists in package path and permission is set to executable (chmod +x)`

So i am running a project, of autonomous navigation, on raspberry pi which, is on my robot. I've connected with ssh etc. to my robot to start the process. I am trying to run gmapping in my computer so can start the visualization of the environment.

I have installed gmapping with the command `sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-slam-gmapping` i also git cloned it from git hub so i can run the launch file (dont ask me why) and when i  execute the command `roslaunch gmapping slam_gmapping_pr2.launch`, which is the launch file, i get this error message.

P.S.: i've sourced my workspace, i've done catkin_make, i've added the permissions for executable (chmod +x) to all files BUT nothing worked and i still see that error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash` on same terminal where you are launching your gmapping launch file because it's saying it can't file the pkg location. This should solve your problem.

If not, can you share the image of your error for better understanding.

Comment: The last line should be a comment under the question. Please do not ask/give feedback in answers.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it !!!
I've noticed that the gmapping package that i git cloned, from which then i would try to use`roslaunch gmapping slam_gmappin_pr2.launch` it wasn't built in devel->lib folder of catkin_ws see:`catkin_ws/devel/lib` no matter how many times `catkin_make` was "theoretically" successful.

You can find if the package is actually built (if you git cloned it) with this command:

- `cd /<path_to_your_workspace>/devel/lib/gmapping/ && ls`

in other case :

- `cd /opt/ros/<your_distro>/lib/gmapping/ && ls`

So !!! There was clearly problem with devel cause were missing some other packages that ive recently thought I've built.So i read some ros answers about how to rebuild my catkin_ws without losing any of the packages that i had and that's how I've done it :

- `rm -rf $HOME/catkin_ws/build $HOME/catkin_ws/devel`
- `source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`
- `cd $HOME/catkin_ws`
- `catkin_make`
- `source $HOME/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`

After that i saw the packages in devel folder right away. Just that, i haven't done anything else.

P.S.:I hope this was helpful cause it took me about 2 hours to find an answer